# How to open Acrobat.exe and use pywinauto to scan PDF files

Tags: pdf, python-3.5, acrobat, scanning, pywinauto

I am having trouble finding a way to do this and am new to the pywinauto world.  I can't get acrobat to open with this code.

```
from pywinauto import *

app = application.Application()

app.start('notepad.exe')
```

I am trying things like this:

```
app.start('acrobat.exe')
```

or app.start('filepath to acrobat').  I do not understant why start acrobat.exe will run the program from the windows cmd shell but is rejected by pywinauto.
I would then like to select file > create > PDF from scanner > color document.  I am aware this is user-like thinking and not programmer-like thinking, but I think it is the quickest and easiest way to start get the PDF's I need.
Please help!  I am grateful for any direction or input to help get things going.  I also can't seem to find any syntax tutorials for pywinauto...Thanks!

Comment: The docs are here: http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/contents.html I'll take a look at the Acrobat tomorrow to see if it can be automated by pywinauto 0.5.4 or new under-development UIA functionality is necessary.

Comment: Generally if Spy++ can see the controls inside the application-under-test, then pywinauto is very good here. If only Inspect.exe can see the controls, then you need an UIA branch (not released yet but available for early testing). If none of these tools are lucky, it seems only coordinate approach can help you.

Comment: I've played with recent Adobe Reader. Spy++ doesn't see the menus, but Inspect.exe can see something. Unfortunately I have no much time to write an example for Acrobat because we're working on new UIA release (while we're free from our main jobs).

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.0 is out. So it can be useful for Acrobat automation now. Feel free to ask more detailed questions if you're still interested.

Answer (score 0):

Clint, I am new to pywinauto, also.  Below is the code to open Acrobat:

import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" ')

app.Kill_()

Vasily Ryabov is correct, you cannot get to the Menu items in Adobe.  I thought of using Tabs to try to navigate the menu (but this is a hacky solution).  You need to specify the path of the application you are trying to automate.  Well there is my 2 cents.  Hope it helps !!

Below is a link to PyWinAuto documentation [Release 0.6.0]:

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pywinauto/uia/pywinauto.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If you using python 3.7 install Pywinauto version 0.5.4

Add your AcroRd.exe path

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe")
```